# How to Connect Different Page Login Form with Joomla Site

Tags: php, joomla

I have problem while trying to integrate my site (build w/ Joomla) with portal (PHP).

I have the index.php from the portal site, but I still can't get how to connected it with Joomla login page. What I want is when I submit the username and password from the portal, my Joomla get connected with my portal user database instead of Joomla user database.

The only clue I got from my friend is try to use the session from the portal. But I still don't understand how to connect it with Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not an easy thing to do. You shoul check if there is some kind of BRIDGE for Joomla and your Portal Software. If not you should write anJoomla  authenfification plugin which takes care on synchronising users between the two softwares.